# Capturar clipboard no Windows com JAVA

Tags: java, área-de-transferência

Há como capturar o clipboard em ambiente Windows com Java?

Eu consigo capturar a tela, mas eu gostaria de capturar o clipboard (é o que fica na memória quando se faz CTRL+C, por exemplo).

Uma simples dica é o suficiente para mim.

Answer (score 5):

Sim, consegues usando a classe [Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html). Eis um exemplo:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```

O método `getData()` e o `stringFlavor` retornam texto puro do Clipboard.

Mais informações:

- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma estudada nisso e qualquer coisa pergunto.